# Using (?<! regex assert without fixed width

Tags: html, regex

I have this regex that works nearly as expected...

```
(?<!color: )(?<!color:)(?<!pid=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\#(\w+)
```

Let's say this is my html code:

```
<span style='color: #FFAABB'><a href='?pid=55155#pid55155'>hey #hello</a></span>
```

The regex only matchs: #hello which is ok but the point is that I don't know how many numbers will be after "pid" and I can't use "?", "*" or "{n,m}" qualifiers with "(?<!)" (I don't know why).

My question is: Is there any way to make it dynamic?

Please don't suggest:

```
(?<!color: )(?<!color:)(?<!pid=[0-9])(?<!pid=[0-9][0-9])(?<!pid=[0-9][0-9][0-9])(?<!pid=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\#(\w+)
```

Because it's awful.

Here is a working example:

https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/1

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which language are you running? php?

Comment: you went fully html-regexed. Never go fully html-regexed. Use a parser instead, and save yourself from getting a headache.

Comment: I'm using MyCode function from Admin panel in MyBB forum board. At the backend it uses php but I didn't edit anything there, I'm only using a tool. (That's why I can't use an xml parser). I'm linking hashtags to twitter in the forum. I'm sure it must be an easy solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language supports `(*SKIP)(*F)`, then you could use simply the below.

```
(?:color:\s*|pid=\d*)#(*SKIP)(*F)|#(\w+)
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/2)

Note that the above `\s` matches newline characters also. So use `\h` to match only the horizontal spaces.

**Explanation:**

- `(?:color:\s*|pid=\d*)#` Matches all the `#` symbols plus the preceding `color:` and the  zero or more spaces OR `|` the `pid=` and zero or more digits. So the part you don't want was matched.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` causes the previous match to fail. And the pattern after `|` will try to match the characters from the remaining string.
- In our case the pattern after `|` is `#` . So `#(\w+)` matches all the hash tags you want.

Comment: The language is php, let's test.

Comment: What does *SKIP do? I didn't get it at all

Answer (score 1):

```
color:\s*#\w+|pid=\d+#\w+|(#\w+)
```

You can try this.Just grab the capture or group.See demo.This matches all crap and captures what you want.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/3

```
$re = "/color:\\s*#\\w+|pid=\\d+#\\w+|(#\\w+)/m";
$str = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">test1<span style=\"color: #FFA500;\">test2</span>test3</span>#hello#how#are#you\n<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">test1<span style=\"color: #FFA500;\">test2</span>test3</span>#lalala #hello\n<div class=\"post_body\" id=\"pid_58705\">\n<blockquote><cite><span> (Hoy 02:42)</span>Moroha escribió: <a class=\"quick_jump\" href=\"http://test.com/Thread-hello?pid=58672#pid58672\" rel=\"nofollow\">&nbsp;</a></cite>testing</blockquote></div>\npid=97589735935795358672#foobar\n<span style='color: #FFAABB'><a href='?pid=55155#pid55155'>hey #hello</a></span>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: @Daii i guess both are correct answers.Just the approach is different.Though this would be easy to understand

Comment: As I said, both works but the proper way to do it is @Avinash way because it is EXACTLY what I wanted. Yours is more like a workaround.